# How to apply custom font-size based on tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I have a navigation menu; whose font-size is 10px for small device, 20px for medium and 50px for large device. Unfortunately I am new to tailwind css.

Now I have written the css as below. Is this correct way, do I need to convert the pixel to rem

```
.nav-link {
  font-size:  10px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-link {
        font-size:  20px;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {

    .nav-link {
        font-size:  50px;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your custom style, just change from `20px` to `10px` on the first declaration...

```css
.nav-link {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use TailwindCSS classes to have almost the same sizes

```html
<a class="text-xs md:text-xl lg:text-5xl">link</a>
```

Excluding the `xs`, which is around `12px`, the other sizes are the same.